# Rename files with its directory name

Tags: php, file-rename

I have some directories with files like:

```
folder1/filename.jpg
folder2/filename.pdf
folder3/filename.jpg
```

And I want to rename all files inside all directories with its corresponding directory name (but keeping its extension), like:

```
folder1/filename.jpg to folder1/folder1.jpg
folder2/filename.pdf to folder2/folder2.pdf
folder3/filename.jpg to folder3/folder3.jpg
```

Edit: also, I want to copy all renamed files to another directory (like "allfiles").

I found [a similar question in Perl language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351479/script-to-rename-files-with-the-name-of-the-folder).

How could I achieve it with PHP?

Comment: This is not a question :S ...

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a way to do that:

```
<?php

// Array with all subdirectories in directory
$dirArray = array_filter(glob('/path/to/directory/*'), 'is_dir');

// $dir is the path to the subdirectory
foreach ($dirArray as $dir) {

    // $dirName has the future name of files in that subdirectory
    $dirName = basename($dir);

    // Take all the elements in the subdirectory (except '.' and '..')
    $filesArray = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.', '..'));

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($filesArray as $file) {
        // Take the file extension for the rename method
        $fileExtension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $oldName = $dir . "/" . $file;
        $newName = $dir . "/" . $dirName . "-" . $i . "." . $fileExtension;

        rename($oldName, $newName);
        $i++;
    }
}
```

If you are sure you will have only one file in each subdirectory you can use this line to `$newName`:

```
$newName = $dir . "/" . $dirName . "." . $fileExtension;
```

Comment: Many thanks, that's what i'm looking for. could you also tell me how can I copy all renamed files to another single folder?

Comment: Copy or move? @Sifur

Comment: copy and keep original file where it was.